# Way to Schedule Follow-Up Meeting using Outlook 2013 Meeting Invites?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Frequently I want to schedule a follow-up meeting to a meeting that has just occurred. I want the same participants, same subject and same body, just sometime in the future.  I can't find a way to do this in Outlook except for to just start over with a new meeting with a new invite and manually copy the participants, subject and body.

The behavior I want is analogous to that of the "Resend this message" option you get in an email.

Anyone have an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two options:

First option (Before [November 8 2023](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-blocks-copying-meetings-with-copying-meetings-is-not-supported-4baaa023-2199-4833-b7ac-d9f0715d50f1#:%7E:text=the%20following%20message%3A-,Copying%20meetings%20is%20not%20supported.,long%2Dstanding%20documented%20best%20practice.)): Copy the meeting. In Calendar view, Ctrl + Left Click Drag the meeting to another day. Double-click on the copied meeting to revise the date/time. Send the new meeting request. Take care to review all the meeting request details in case you need to change venue, body text, etc.

Second option: Double-click on existing meeting, change the details, and send an update. Second option is likely less desirable as it does not keep a record of the meeting that took place.

Comment: When I'm not the sender ("owner") of the original meeting, this just gives me a fairly useless read-only copy.

Answer (score 14):

In Outlook 2016:

1. In calendar view, select meeting
2. In ribbon, select "Reply All"
3. File > Save (or <kbd>⌘S</kbd>) to save as draft
4. Close the draft window
5. Go to Drafts folder
6. On ribbon, click "Meeting" (small button next to Forward)

Now you have a new meeting with the same invitees, subject, and body content as the original.

Doesn't solve everything (location, duration, optional/required, etc) but easier than copypasting each element separately into a new meeting!

Comment: Works like a charm. Ridiculous that M$ makes this so difficult.

Comment: This method seems to work best if you aren't the creator of the original meeting.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a quick play and the only way I can see at present is to write a macro. Of course, not all organisations allow Outlook macro's.

I would probably get the details from the selected calendar entry, create a new calendar entry open in the UI maybe with 7d added to the meeting date.

Comment: Actually, sunk818's answer (http://superuser.com/a/893961/464136) is perfect. You should check it out.

Comment: Yes, I do that all the time - in fact I was perhaps over engineering a "solution" since that's what the question alluded to. Obviously copying a meeting then changing is is NOT the same as a resend this message button. But, as you say, it works.