# How can I copy an existing MS Outlook element (mail, calender entry) into a new element?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, calendar

In IBM Notes there is a function "Copy into new" that can be applied to existing e-mails, calendar entries etc. This is very handy when you want send a mail similar to one you have already sent, with the same recipients etc. or when you want to schedule a meeting similar to an existing one, with the same participants etc.

Of course I know that you can *forward* a mail or calendar entry in MS Outlook, but this adds additional forwarding text and doesn't contain the former recipients / participants including CC and BCC.

So is there a way to clone existing mails / calendar entries as new mail / calendar drafts in MS Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

I found answers to my question here:

E-Mail: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/resend-an-email-message-acd16ac4-c881-477d-b4aa-36168fa96088

Calender entry: [Way to Schedule Follow-Up Meeting using Outlook 2013 Meeting Invites?](https://superuser.com/questions/893897/way-to-schedule-follow-up-meeting-using-outlook-2013-meeting-invites)

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.